# Trying to Add Files to an Empty C# Web Application Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure

I have inherited a mess of a C# Web Application from previous developers and I am trying to create a working Visual Studio Web Application from the previous files.

Unfortunately the previous developers left a rather large mess. To give you an idea of how messed up the software is, they were using notepad to make changes to the project files on the Microsoft Azure server! They configured Azure in such a way that it is not possible to publish to Azure using Visual Studio. Also other incorrect things they did was only having 1 instance of the web application, and also not linking the web application to source control.

Also the previous developers left no documentation.

These developers created a single solution with 6 different projects, for right now, I am only interested in the project that is a web application written in C#. When I mapped the solution out of team services, there was no way to start the web application in debug mode, Visual Studio Debug refuses to recognize the Web Application.

SO what I am doing is I have created a new empty web application project in Visual Studio, and I want to add the files to it from the Web Application I inherited from the previous developers, and hope to run it then in debug mode so I can do testing and validation of any changes I make to the project.

When I copy in a file, such as a .aspx file and its .cs code behind file, the project does not recognize it. If I choose Add->Existing Item then I can browse to the files and add them to the project. Then Visual Studio recognizes the files.

However when I copy and paste in a folder to the project using windows explorer, Visual Studio does not recognize it, and also there is no way to add a folder using the ADD->Existing Item method. The only way visual studio will recognize a folder is if you choose the Add->New Folder option, But I want to avoid doing that for each folder in the Web Application, I just want to copy them in at one time using Windows Explorer.

Is there a way to copy in a folder of files into the project using windows explorer and have Visual Studio recognize the folder and show it in solution explorer?

Also I was thinking of mapping the files in from team services, but would have the same issue of Visual Studio not recognizing the folders, unless there is a way?

Comment: How about "Show All Files" and "Include in Project" option on the folder? Have you tried that?

Comment: I second Gaurav's comment. Copy the files to the new location within your project. Then in VS, have "Show All Files". Once the files are shown, right-click the files and "Include in Project"

Comment: Ok thanks, that does exactly what I need to do, thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Also, if you decide to migrate to ASPNet Core 1.0, you won't need to ever do a Project include or Add Existing File ever again.

Answer (score 0):

Show all files in your project and then right click the files to add and choose Include in Project:

[image]

[image]